# How to get terminal window inside Visual Studio 2017 / 2019?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I was just reading this article - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-studio-2019-net-productivity-2/ and noticed in one of the GIF image, she is showing a terminal window inside VS editor itself. It looks like a fully fledged powershell window. How can we get that? Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just update my answer, any update ? Or maybe I misunderstand your meaning. If so, please feel free to correct me :(

Comment: In addition, you can find source code in [Microsoft/WhackWhackTerminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/WhackWhackTerminal).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> > How can we get that?

The Terminal Window in the video seems to comes from a VS extension [Whack Whack Terminal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal).
You can download and install it in your vs2017.

(Note:For vs2017, it should be higher versions than 15.6+)

For more details(usage and settings) please check [Adding a terminal window to Visual Studio 2017](http://hermit.no/adding-a-terminal-window-to-visual-studio-2017/) or [A proper terminal for Visual Studio](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AProperTerminalForVisualStudio.aspx)

**Update:**

1.After install the extension, `ctrl+\` twice, then the terminal window will show at the bottom of vs window. And we can change the layout by draging the window like below:

[image]

2.Hope it's what you want. Also we can Go Tools=>Options=>keyboard to change the shortcut setting of this window:

[image]

**Update:**

VS 2019 16.3+ added the terminal window as a preview feature. Thanks for the info from **Farhad** and **Platinums**! Related info see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/).

Comment: I just added Whack Whack Terminal to VS.NET 2019 Community 16.0.1 and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes,it works for vs2017 and vs2019 now. And for vs2017, it should be 15.6+.

Comment: Perfectly worked for me, just VS 2019 16.3+ added the terminal window as a preview feature. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

Comment: Some more details about the VS 2019 16.3+ terminal window: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

Answer (score 7):

This is now a native feature in the latest Preview Version (Preview 3)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

It is now available in VS 2019 version 16.6: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/the-powershell-you-know-and-love-now-with-a-side-of-visual-studio/

However, I still prefer Whack Whack since you can't seem to change the font size.