# Can't Open Terminal window which is not currently available in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm new in .net Visual Studio 2019. I'm facing problem is not find terminal in vs2019.

I'm try to **Ctrl** + \ see the message:

[image]

Also not found in **view > Other Windows**

[image]

But in **Tools > options > Keyboard** I can see the global command

[image]

Thank you in advance ....!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get terminal window inside Visual Studio 2017 / 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486219/how-to-get-terminal-window-inside-visual-studio-2017-2019)

Comment: please look at the first screen. In above questions open terminal but I can't.

Comment: @ViralPatel the first screen doesn't show any terminal, it's the Output Window as the tab name says. Are you asking about [this terminal perhaps](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioNowIncludesAnIntegratedTerminal.aspx) ? That's available in  Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 3  and later as a preview feature

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can get to Terminal in VS is "Package Manager Console" (View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console).

Despite its name, it is a PowerShell based console that allows you to execute pretty much any DOS or PowerShell command installed on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

The first screen shows the `Output Window`, not a terminal. The menu in the second picture shows the shortcut, `Ctrl+Alt+O`.

Visual Studio didn't have a terminal until recently. Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 3 added [experimental integration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) with [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-4-release/), itself a preview feature released this summer to the Windows Insider ring.

To enable it, you need first install `Windows Terminal` from [the Windows App Store](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiF1uvO8ObkAhVlyaYKHU4VCe4QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fp%2Fwindows-terminal-preview%2F9n0dx20hk701&usg=AOvVaw1r9kXU3mD1bT7lZcbglF34). After that, go to `Tools > Options > Preview Features` page and check `Experimental VS Terminal` :

[image]